# A simple True/False question regarding linear approximation in two variables

Tags: calculus, functions, linear-approximation

True/False question:
If the linear approximation of a function f at a point P is a constant function, then P is a critical point.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The linear approximation is given by the tangent line. If it is a constant function, what is the slope of the tangent there?

Comment: I was able to solve the question, thanks!